# Python process killed - docker, aws and conda issue

Tags: python, linux, docker, amazon-ec2, conda

I have a python script that runs fine locally on cloud 9. I'm migrating it to fargate (codebuild). I had some usual issues that I worked through where it wasn't finding python modules etc and was just adding them to the environment. It seems those issue have been resolved but I get a really weird kill message from python. This is the error message I'm getting from the logs;

```
ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(33): Subprocess for 'conda run ['python', 'server.py']' command failed.  (See above for error)

/opt/conda/envs/myenv/.tmpjsztda5o: line 3:    22 Killed                  python server.py
```

The fargate logs weirdly show that these error changes a little each time it  runs (its producing a new attempt to run every ~2-3 minutes). e.g.

```
ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(33): Subprocess for 'conda run ['python', 'server.py']' command failed.  (See above for error)
/opt/conda/envs/myenv/.tmp3hrkajas: line 3:    21 Killed                  python server.py
```

This is the Dockerfile.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lts/ubuntu:latest
RUN echo Updating existing packages, installing and upgrading python and pip.

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install build-essential -y
RUN apt-get install g++ -y
RUN apt-get install gcc -y
RUN apt-get install gdal-bin -y
RUN which gcc 
RUN echo $PATH

FROM osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-latest
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
WORKDIR /app
## Create the environment:
COPY environment.yml .
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml
#Make RUN commands use the new environment:
RUN echo "conda activate myenv" >> ~/.bashrc
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "myenv", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

# Demonstrate the environment is activated:
RUN echo "Make sure flask is installed:"
RUN python -c "import flask"


RUN echo Copy service directory

COPY ./PHREEQC /PHREEQC
COPY ./service /service
COPY ./temp_files /temp_files
COPY ./INPUT_DATA /INPUT_DATA

WORKDIR /service

ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "myenv", "python","server.py"]
```

Let me know if you have any thoughts on how to start debugging this problem!

**ANSWER**

Thanks to itamar I was able to solve the problem by increasing the size of the container

Thanks itamar, this did turn out to be a memory issue so reconfigured the ECR instance to a slightly larger one.

1. Deregister existing task definitions ->

`aws ecs deregister-task-definition --task-definition ecs_name:ID`

2. Register new task definition with updated size.

Size -> Change from cpu 256 and memory 512 to ->

```
 "family": "fam_name",
 "cpu": "1024",
 "memory": "4096",
 "networkMode": "awsvpc",
 "requiresCompatibilities": [
   "FARGATE"....
```

then

`aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://~/environment/aws-cli/task-definition.json`

3. Update the service

`aws ecs update-service --cluster name-Cluster --service name-Service --task-definition ecs_name:ID`

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Unrelated to your main question, it might be better to use one of the compilers packaged by Conda itself rather the operating system compiler, just so things like libstdc++ dependency line up.

Comment: Another suggestion: you're creating two images, and just throwing away the first one it seems like. You can throw everything away before "FROM continuumio/miniconda3" and still get same effect. You are not combining the images, as you might think, you are just creating a series of 3 images and only using the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your process is being killed (which is distinct from crashing), the most likely issue is that it's running out memory.

- Linux has heuristics where it tries to detect applications that are using too much memory, and then kill -9s them (macOS has similar system).
- Within a container, there are also memory limits that when hit will kill your process.

See https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-out-of-memory/ for other symptoms.

A first pass suggestion: configure your container with more memory. E.g. if you're using Fargate you can give your task more memory, up to 30GB. If 30GB is not enough, you'll need to run it elsewhere or reduce memory usage.

To get a sense of memory usage you can use https://pythonspeed.com/fil/. You can find suggestions on reducing memory usage at https://pythonspeed.com/memory/.